# break text in textview according by size of screen (Android)

Tags: android, text, textview

i want create book reader app that paging like as book and not scrolling.
how calculate count of line of text in a page attention to changing of screen size and font size ?
thanks

Comment: Please be more specific? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically you want to know when a page is filled up with text you want to break the text and start in another page. Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: oe jamwal tu a?krda zra main downvote.. :p

Comment: yes AlexBalo. i want to know when a page is filled up with text i want to break the text and start in another page

Comment: nobalG : i'm not understand, please type EN

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and extend View class. Then in `onDraw()` function you can draw text in canvas using `canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);`.

From canvas we where able to get the height and width of current view and also the width of text can be calculated. Then you can write a code according to your needs.

Comment: JM India : please give me algorithm of how calculate a mount of text shown in this page that in other page show countinue of text. thanks